# How to fetch contact_id using customer phone number in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ivr, amazon-connect

I am trying to fetch all the contact ids using phone number of customers in nodejs. But I was not able to find anything for that. Is there any way or tip how can I achieve this?

The motive behind it is want to show the contact ids and call details (date-time of call) in my program just like we use contact search of amazon connect (contact lens).

Answer (score 1):

That isn't possible in nodejs. There is no API for reporting in Connect.

The solution here is to setup the Kinesis stream for the Connect Contact Trace Records to populate a Glue database. You can then query this via Athena.

There is a blog post [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/analyze-amazon-connect-contact-trace-record-with-amazon-athena-and-amazon-quicksight-part-1/) that will take you through the process.

Comment: Using S3 and Athena would be extremely expensive and slow. You probably don't have enough data to justify this approach. Better to store the CTRs in DynamoDB.

Comment: The most expensive part of that solution is the Kinesis stream, and you are going to need that anyway as it is the only way to get the CTRs out of Connect. Also it isn't slow, that blog takes you through getting the CTR records into parquet files with partitioning and the queries are fine, particularly with date clauses.

Comment: Kinesis is not the only way to get CTRs out of Connect, you can subscribe to Event Bridge directly. However, I'm not sure if it's going to be cheaper. Also, I don't think you can compare dynamo DB latency to Athena + s3. Honestly, I can hardly see any reason to use Athena + s3. This approach fits "big data" - but in most contact centres, the amount of records is not that big and can sit in any database.